# How can I convert 23 years 0 months into numerical value so that I can use it in Predictive Modelling

Tags: excel, pandas, python-2.7, data-science, data-modeling

I have a dataset in which values are in this form

23 years 0 months or 
2 years 6 months

How can I convert it in numerical data or any other form so that it can be used in predictive modelling , Using pandas

Comment: Are these string values, `'23 years 0 months'`?

Comment: Also, what kind of representation do you want? years (and especially months) aren't a precisely defined unit of time with respect to seconds for instance. But perhaps you'd want 2 years 6 months to be 2.5?

Comment: Is it possible that I can make two columns 23 and 6 .? I'm a beginner

Comment: I think 2 years 6 months as 2.5 is my answer , athanks alollz and omerA

Answer (score 1):

Based on what ALollz said in the comments, you could split the line by spaces and add the months as a percentage of a year

```
a = "23 years 6 months"
b = a.split(" ")

print(str(float(b[0]) + float(b[2])/12))
```

Output: `23.5`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of coding to let me easily change the output in the future so this is what I came up with:

```py
convs = {'ye': 1, 'mo': 12, 'we': 52.1429, 'da': 365}  # conversion rates to a year

conv_to = 'ye'  # choose your desired unit!
times = {i: convs[conv_to] / float(convs[i]) for i in convs}

s = "1 year 1 month 1 week 1 day"
s = s.split(" ")
s = list(zip(s[0::2], s[1::2]))

converted_amt = sum([float(times[i[1].lower()[:2]]) * float(i[0]) for i in s])

print(converted_amt)
```

With that you can easily add more granularity to support hours minutes, and more.

Input:

`conv_to = 'mo'
s = "23 years 2 months 3 weeks 24 days"`

Output:
`279.4794514873339`

Input:

`conv_to = 'ye'
s = "8 years 9 months 0 weeks 3 day"`

Output:

`3196.75`

Input (works with any order):

`conv_to = 'da'
s = "2 days 1 week"`

Output:

`8.999994246580073`

As you can see it won't be totally accurate converting to days when weeks are used, as the value I use is an average found on Google. Rounding should help this.